# How do I remove the axis tick marks on seaborn heatmap

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, axis-labels

I have a seaborn heatmap but i need to remove the axis tick marks that show as dashes. I want the tick labels but just need to remove the dash (-) at each tick on both axes. My current code is:

```
sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, fmt='.2f', center=0)
```

[image]

I tried despine and that didnt work.

Comment: `ax.tick_params(left=False, bottom=False)`?

Comment: that did the trick. I actually tried that before asking but I had entered the line before the sns.heatmap() line. Is there a reason why it doesn't work if plt.tick_params() is placed before sns.heatmap()??

Comment: The problem is that before you call `sns.heatmap` there is no axes around for those parameters to apply to. Hence I would suggest to use  `ax = sns.heatmap(..); ax.tick_param(..)` from which it is clear that you need an `ax` for it to work.

Answer (score 11):

@ImportanceOfBeingEarnest had a nice answer in the comments that I wanted to add as an answer (in case the comment gets deleted).

For a `heatmap`:

```py
ax = sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, fmt='.2f', center=0)
ax.tick_params(left=False, bottom=False) ## other options are right and top
```

If this were instead a `clustermap` (like here [How to remove x and y axis labels in a clustermap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234158/how-to-remove-x-and-y-axis-labels-in-a-clustermap)), you'd have an extra call:

```py
g = sns.clustermap(...)
g.ax_heatmap.tick_params(left=False, bottom=False)
```

And for anyone who wanders in here looking for the related task of removing **tick labels**, see this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26428792/3407933).

Comment: The answer above on ```clustermap``` did not work for me. Instead I used: ```g.ax_heatmap.tick_params(tick2On=False, labelsize=False)```. This did remove the ticks and their labels.

Answer (score 3):

```
ax = sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, fmt='.2f', center=0)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', length=0)
```

`ax` is a `matplotlib.axes` object. All axes parameters can be changed in this object, and here's an example from the matplotlib tutorial on how to [change tick parameters](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html). `both` selects both `x` and `y` axis, and then their `length` is changed to 0, so that the ticks are not visible anymore.

Comment: Please add some explanation.